# OnClick event only works second time

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, onclicklistener

I have a button that when used to run a asyntask class, I use it for set into a value in a textView. When he returns to the class that called the method, the value of the TextView caught and put in a Toast but the first time I click the Toast not appear any message, in the second works. What to do?

This is the method that calls the button

```
btnDadosPessoais.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String pega = TextAux.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), pega, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            gravarDadoss(view);
        }
    });
```

TV is my TextView, I'm putting a simple string

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String resposta) {
    if(resposta.equals("Sem acesso à Internet")&&dialog.isShowing())
    {
        tv.setText(resposta);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    else if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        valida(resposta);
    }
}
```

Asyntask here

`public class BackgroudCadPessoa extends AsyncTask {

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
Context ctx;
String pega;
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
TextView tv;

BackgroudCadPessoa(Context ctx, View v) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textAux);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    dialog.setMessage("Aguarde...");
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if (connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        String urls = "my URL";
        String nome = params[0];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("nome", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(nome, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        return "Sem acesso à Internet";
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String resposta) {
    if(resposta.equals("Sem acesso à Internet")&&dialog.isShowing())
    {
        tv.setText(resposta);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    else if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        valida(resposta);
    }
}

public void valida(String js)
{
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    if (js.equals(null)) {
        tv.setText("Erro ao Cadastrar");
    } else {
        try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(js);
            jsonArray = jo.getJSONArray("Resposta");
            int count = 0;
            while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                pega = jsonObject.getString("resposta");
                count++;
            }
            if (pega == null)
            {
                tv.setText("Erro ao Cadastrar");
            }
            else if (pega.equals("Dados Cadastrados"))
            {
                tv.setText("Dados Cadastrados");
            }
            else if (pega.equals("Erro ao Cadastrar"))
            {
                tv.setText("Erro ao Cadastrar");
            }
            else
            {
                tv.setText("Dados Cadastrados");
            }
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: Can you share the related code?

Comment: Post Some Code.

Comment: Please add some code. Without it we are very much unable to help ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but where is the AsyncTask?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your code works as expected. The AsyncTask will return some text after you click the button once. Then it sets the textview. When you click the button again, that text is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You want your Toast to appear AFTER your AsyncTask finishes its output to TextAux?

Then you need to put your toaster in the onPostExecute

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String resposta) {
    if(resposta.equals("Sem acesso à Internet")&&dialog.isShowing())
    {
        tv.setText(resposta);
        dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), resposta, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        valida(resposta);
    }

}
```